# How do I match and block a tag by an attribute's value with Ublock Origin?

Tags: adblock, ublock-origin

I'm trying to block/remove a specific stylesheet from a page. The context here is that this stylesheet is the stylesheet specific to a specific subreddit. The HTML looks like this (from the [ublock origin subreddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ref="applied_subreddit_stylesheet" title="applied_subreddit_stylesheet" type="text/css" jr9j7vt="" href="https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/x1EvRnEHlyWqignh2O2sB2jqVs7clKIcjooIGRfYMVY.css" >
```

This sounded like an application for [procedural cosmetic filters](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Procedural-cosmetic-filters), so I added this reddit-specific xpath filter:

```
reddit.com##:xpath(//link[@title = 'applied_subreddit_stylesheet'])
```

That doesn't work. The page still looks like this image, which indicates that the custom stylesheet is still loaded:

[image: ublock origin subreddit with custom stylesheet]

It should look like this image, which is after I delete the custom stylesheet through inspect element:

[image: ublock origin subreddit without custom stylesheet]

I'm using uBlock Origin v1.22.2 and Firefox ESR v68.2.0esr, both from the Debian 10 ("buster") repositories. Downloading Firefox and/or uBlock Origin from outside the repositories is not an option on this system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [uBlock - create filter based on pattern of an attribute such as div\[data-link.contains()\]](https://superuser.com/questions/1549030/ublock-create-filter-based-on-pattern-of-an-attribute-such-as-divdata-link-co)

Comment: Note -- the dupe target has an actual answer that addresses how to use attributes in block filters. This question does not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Block stylesheets coming from the `b.thumbs.redditmedia.com` URL directly:

```
||b.thumbs.redditmedia.com^$css
```

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to block via attributes.