# uBlock - create filter based on pattern of an attribute such as div[data-link.contains()]

Tags: css, ublock-origin

I would like to hide news links to rt.com from duckduckgo. I can create a filter for a particular link, like

```
duckduckgo.com##div[data-link="https://www.rt.com/news/487829-germany-gru-warrant-hacker/"]
```

But how can I achieve this (doesn't work):

```
duckduckgo.com##div[data-link="https://www.rt.com/*"]
```

Answer (score 13):

One can use a [css attribute prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Syntax):

```
duckduckgo.com##div[data-link^="https://www.rt.com/"]
```